# Ember.js: How to render hasMany relationship along with all possible values

Tags: ember.js

Here is part of my model:

```
App.Cheese = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    category: DS.attr('string'),
    flavors: DS.hasMany('flavor', { async: true })
});

App.Flavor = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

When a Cheese is displayed, the list of all existing `flavor` should be displayed as buttons.
If the cheese being displayed already has a given flavor, the color of the associated button should reflect that.
Clicking on a button should add / remove the association between the current cheese and the flavor underlying the clicked button.

In the template displaying the cheese, we would have:

```
Name: {{name}}
Flavors:
{{#each flavor in allFavors}}
    <button class="(depends on whether the cheese has this flavor)">{{flavor.name}}</button>
{{/each}}
</code>
</pre>
```

Plus, each button would be bound to the model's relationship between the cheese and the underlying flavor, so that when the user clicks, the model gets updated and vice-versa.

What would be a satisfying way to handle this in Ember?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I came up with which I would be happy to receive comments on.

The observation is, I likened the relationship described above as a matrix.
Indeed, for each cheese, there are a set of possible values, and for each cheese-flavor relationship, there is a boolean saying whether or not the two are related.

It is questionable to store a relationship that means "there is no relationship", and this is why I find this solution far from perfect.
But at least it allows me to have Ember display the relationship easily and have Ember bind two-ways the template and the model.

Here is the new code, to better understand the problem:

```
App.Cheese = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    category: DS.attr('string'),
    flavors: DS.hasMany('cheeseFlavor', { async: true })
});

App.CheeseFlavor = DS.Model.extend({
    cheese: DS.belongsTo('cheese'),
    flavor: DS.belongsTo('flavor'),
    doesHave: DS.attr('boolean')
});

App.Flavor = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Cheese.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [
        {id: 1, name: 'Cheddar', category: 'cat1', flavors: [1, 2, 3]},
        {id: 2, name: 'Blue Cheese', category: 'cat6', flavors: [4, 5, 6]},
    ]
});

App.CheeseFlavor.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [
        {id: 1, cheese: 1, flavor: 1, doesHave: true},
        {id: 2, cheese: 1, flavor: 2, doesHave: false},
        {id: 3, cheese: 1, flavor: 3, doesHave: true},
        {id: 4, cheese: 2, flavor: 1, doesHave: false},
        {id: 5, cheese: 2, flavor: 2, doesHave: false},
        {id: 6, cheese: 2, flavor: 3, doesHave: true}
    ]
});

App.Flavor.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [
        {id: 1, name: 'Flavor 1'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Flavor 2'},
        {id: 3, name: 'Flavor 3'}
    ]
});
```